# how to decide a variable to be a factor or integer in regression

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression

say while predicting the house price variables like the number of bedrooms, bathrooms, floors, condition has a very small range and in integers. should we proceed these variables being integers or need to convert into factors?[click here to see the str of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KbPf.png)
[price vs bedroom scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OFbx.png)

Comment: I would use number of bedrooms, bathrooms, floors as categorical variables. But lot size and sq ft inside the house as numerical.

Comment: thank you for the response, but why can't we use the variables bathrooms, bedrooms or floors as integers or numeric?

Comment: You could decide to do that. I told you what I would try first, based on some experience. One potential problem with using small integer values as numeric is that they are pretty clearly not normal. I would need to know all the variables and see some data before being sure what to do.

Comment: Put supporting data in the question, not comments. Also take care about the formatting.

Comment: And whatever you do, _delete that comment_ with the table. It is messing up the format of all the other comments too.

Comment: I added the str of dataset in the question

Comment: It is unlikely that the value of a house increase in a linear fashion as the number of bedrooms increases so use a category variable. If after inspection it turns out that it is linear then you can convert back to integer as this would require using fewer coefficients which is preferable.

Comment: -user121049  I have added the scatter plot of price vs bedrooms, it seem to have a linear relation. how could you interpret this and decide bedrooms as factor or not?